# Java JFrame tiles

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

i am currently attempting to make a fractal terrain generator using the diamonds and squares algorithm. I have the algorithm completed (I think)  but I don't know how to use `JFrames` very well.

How would I get this to display the tiles?

```
package fractal.terrain;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public int mapSize = 257;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        double tileData[][] = new double[m.mapSize][m.mapSize];
        Random r = new Random();
        final double seed = r.nextInt(10000 - 500 + 1);
        System.out.println("The seed is " + seed);
        tileData[0][0] = tileData[0][m.mapSize - 1] = tileData[m.mapSize - 1][0]
                = tileData[m.mapSize - 1][m.mapSize - 1] = seed;
        double h = 10000.0;

        for (int sideLength = m.mapSize - 1; sideLength >= 2; sideLength /= 2) {
            int halfSide = sideLength / 2;

            for (int x = 0; x < m.mapSize - 1; x += sideLength) {
                for (int y = 0; y < m.mapSize - 1; y += sideLength) {
                    double avg = tileData[x][y]
                            + tileData[x + sideLength][y]
                            + tileData[x][y + sideLength]
                            + tileData[x + sideLength][y + sideLength];
                    avg /= 4.0;

                    tileData[x + halfSide][y + halfSide] = avg + (r.nextDouble() * 2 * h) - h;
                }
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < m.mapSize - 1; x += halfSide) {
                for (int y = (x + halfSide) % sideLength; y < m.mapSize - 1; y += sideLength) {
                    double avg = tileData[(x - halfSide + m.mapSize) % m.mapSize][y]
                            + tileData[(x + halfSide) % m.mapSize][y]
                            + tileData[x][(y + halfSide) % m.mapSize]
                            + tileData[x][(y - halfSide + m.mapSize) % m.mapSize];
                    avg /= 4.0;
                    avg = avg + (r.nextDouble() * 2 * h) - h;
                    tileData[x][y] = avg;
                    if (x == 0) {
                        tileData[m.mapSize - 1][y] = avg;
                    }
                    if (y == 0) {
                        tileData[x][m.mapSize - 1] = avg;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make **one** JFrame and place a JPanel in it, and draw in that JPanel. Myself, I'd draw into a BufferedImage and then display the BufferedImage in a JPanel's `paintComponent` method. Read the Swing tutorials for more details.

Comment: Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).  You will want to create a custom class extending from `JPanel` which you override it's `paintComponent` and perform your custom painting within it.  You will also want to look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: What does all the data mean?

Comment: The data is randomly generated from the seed to make different terrain features such as mountains with snowy peaks or dark blue oceans. It is all based on elevation.

Comment: So each value represents what?  An image?  A drawing method?  A pixel color?  A shape?

Comment: They represent a pixel color based on elevation

Comment: BTW - I don't think your algorithm is correct.  No matter what the seed is, it produces [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LTGuI.png).  As to approaching the GUI, I'd look to first generate the image, then display it in a `JLabel`..

Comment: Oh, I'm going to update the code, I screwed up the random generation. And about the JLabel, do you recommend making a class called Tile or something to paint it?

Comment: @Asourcious Stupid question, is it in row/col order or col/row order? Do the doubles represent a percentage of a color or a packed int value (which needs to be converted to RGB)?

Comment: It is an int that will be run through an if statement checking its elevation, for instance if it is below x, it is dark blue, for deep water, if it is between x and y, light blue for shallow water, etc.

Answer (score 0):

override the draw method on a JPanel and cycle through the array drawing different colored Rectangles for each value.

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int x = 0; x < m.mapSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < m.mapSize; y++) {
            //check each tile and assign in a color based on its value
            if(tileData[x][y] == aCertainNumber){
                g.setColor();
            }
            g.fillRect(x*10, y*10, 10, 10);
        }
    }
```

this should display each tile 10 pixels by 10 pixels

you could also output to an image with

```
BufferedImage map = new BufferedImage(mapSize, mapSize,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int x = 0; x < mapSize; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < mapSize; y++) {
            if(mapData[x][y]==aCertainNumber)
            map.setRGB(x, y, theColorYouWant.getRGB());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating how to break the paint chain and introduce paint random artefacts which I'm sure the OP will enjoy posting more questions about, not to mention the future questions about how to solve the flickering issues this will create.  Overriding `paint` on any component is highly unrecommended and generally discouraged

Comment: if this is just to visualize things and not for and actual game then this should be fine.  if it is for actual game play then yes, OP should probably look into Slick2d or something to make the window XP

Comment: The OP doesn't have the experience to "know" bad code from "good", you've presented a "bad" implementation of an idea which the OP will follow on faith and while it might immediately do so, it will blow up in there face. As a professional forum, we should always be trying to present professional answers and code examples - IMHO